# Cannot compile my PHP-CPP extension with libpqxx on 64-bit system

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, libpqxx

I migrated to 64-bit Ubuntu, and now I can't compile my extension. On 32-bit it works just fine. Someone know what is a problem? Thank you. I've got this error report.

```
        $ make
        g++ -shared -o extension.so main.o -lphpcpp -lpqxx -lpq -fPIC
        /usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libpqxx.a(connection_base.o): 
relocation R_X86_64_32 against `_ZN4pqxx17broken_connectionD1Ev'
    can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
        //usr/local/lib/libpqxx.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
        collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
        make: *** [extension.so] Error 1
```

Comment: I solved it on my own.
http://jaytaylor.com/blog/2010/10/06/howto-fix-fpic-errors/

Comment: You could mention the solution and the link in the answer. But the commented link is not working.

Comment: Sorry man, link worked but times they are changing, and now i'm no longer using PHP-CPP framework. But if someone have same problem, i mean recompile libpqxx with -fPIC was solution.